# Pre-select default value in drop down list

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf, selected

I have created a drop down list in Thymeleaf and it is functional. However, I also want to have a option in the drop down list be pre-selected.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<select id="selectOptions" th:field="*{selectedOption}">
        <option th:each="option : ${searchOptions}"
                th:value="${option.getOption()}"
                th:text="${option.getOptionName()}">Options</option>
</select>
```

How would I use the `th:selected` tag with this? I do not see any documentation on this on their website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectOptions" th:field="*{selectedOption}">
    <option th:each="option : ${searchOptions}"
    th:value="${option.getOption()}"
    th:selected="${option.someOption()}" // <- use the th:selected
    th:text="${option.getOptionName()}">Options</option>
</select>
```